# Time lag variable

Tags: r

unfortunately, I need to completely re-edit the post as my initially proposed data snippet was not entirely reflecting my data set. Essentially my data set looks like below:

```
date       id     person   member_since   consistent
May 2015   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Jul 2015   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Sep 2015   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Nov 2015   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Jan 2016   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
May 2016   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Jul 2016   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Aug 2016   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Mar 2017   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Apr 2017   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
May 2017   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
```

I would now like to create entries on a monthly basis until the month of "member_since", keeping everything constant (see below). Additionally, there will be some variables marked as "consistent"= No (not shown here), which should remain as is.

```
date       id     person   member_since   consistent
Sep 2008   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Oct 2008   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Nov 2008   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
.
.
.
May 2015   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Jul 2015   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Sep 2015   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Nov 2015   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Jan 2016   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
May 2016   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Jul 2016   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Aug 2016   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Mar 2017   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
Apr 2017   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
May 2017   2732   3041     2008-09-17     Yes
```

Can you please help me with the code?

The proposed code below I think is on the right track but doesn't yield yet to the desired outcome.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

monthly_series <- (seq.Date(min(as.Date(df$member_since)),
                            as.Date("2017-05-01"),by="months"))


df2 <-
  df%>%
  group_by(Person)%>%
  merge(monthly_series)%>%
  dplyr::filter((consistent=="Yes"&as.yearmon(as.Date(member_since))<=as.yearmon(y))|
                  (consistent=="No"& as.yearmon(as.Date(member_since))==as.yearmon(y))) %>%
  mutate(Month=as.yearmon(y)) %>%
  select(-y) %>%
  arrange(Person)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Is your data in a CSV file format. Also in the output shown by you there is an entry with Applicable as 'No' as well. Do you want that also in the output. Thanks

Comment: yes, it's in CSV format and I'd also like to keep the applicable as "no" in the final output. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do that with `dplyr` with the help of `yearmon` from package `zoo`.

Basically, the idea is to create a monthly date vector with `seq.Date` and `merge` it with your original data.frame. Then, you can `filter` out the rows that are not wanted. I'm using `dplyr::filter` because `filter` is masked by another package on my machine. On yours, using `filter` by itself might be sufficient.

```
library(dplyr);library(zoo)
df <- read.table(text="Person Member_since  Applicable
A      2013-08-04    Yes
B      2011-12-23    No
C      2014-09-03    Yes",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

monthly_series <- (seq.Date(min(as.Date(df$Member_since)),
                     as.Date("2017-05-01"),by="months"))

df%>%
  group_by(Person)%>%
  merge(monthly_series)%>%
  dplyr::filter((Applicable=="Yes"&as.yearmon(as.Date(Member_since))<=as.yearmon(y))|
                (Applicable=="No"& as.yearmon(as.Date(Member_since))==as.yearmon(y))) %>%
  mutate(Month=as.yearmon(y)) %>%
  select(-y) %>%
  arrange(Person)



   Person Member_since Applicable    Month
1       A   2013-08-04        Yes Aug 2013
2       A   2013-08-04        Yes Sep 2013
3       A   2013-08-04        Yes Oct 2013
4       A   2013-08-04        Yes Nov 2013
5       A   2013-08-04        Yes Dec 2013
6       A   2013-08-04        Yes Jan 2014
7       A   2013-08-04        Yes Feb 2014
8       A   2013-08-04        Yes Mar 2014
9       A   2013-08-04        Yes Apr 2014
10      A   2013-08-04        Yes May 2014
11      A   2013-08-04        Yes Jun 2014
12      A   2013-08-04        Yes Jul 2014
13      A   2013-08-04        Yes Aug 2014
14      A   2013-08-04        Yes Sep 2014
15      A   2013-08-04        Yes Oct 2014
16      A   2013-08-04        Yes Nov 2014
17      A   2013-08-04        Yes Dec 2014
18      A   2013-08-04        Yes Jan 2015
19      A   2013-08-04        Yes Feb 2015
20      A   2013-08-04        Yes Mar 2015
21      A   2013-08-04        Yes Apr 2015
22      A   2013-08-04        Yes May 2015
23      A   2013-08-04        Yes Jun 2015
24      A   2013-08-04        Yes Jul 2015
25      A   2013-08-04        Yes Aug 2015
26      A   2013-08-04        Yes Sep 2015
27      A   2013-08-04        Yes Oct 2015
28      A   2013-08-04        Yes Nov 2015
29      A   2013-08-04        Yes Dec 2015
30      A   2013-08-04        Yes Jan 2016
31      A   2013-08-04        Yes Feb 2016
32      A   2013-08-04        Yes Mar 2016
33      A   2013-08-04        Yes Apr 2016
34      A   2013-08-04        Yes May 2016
35      A   2013-08-04        Yes Jun 2016
36      A   2013-08-04        Yes Jul 2016
37      A   2013-08-04        Yes Aug 2016
38      A   2013-08-04        Yes Sep 2016
39      A   2013-08-04        Yes Oct 2016
40      A   2013-08-04        Yes Nov 2016
41      A   2013-08-04        Yes Dec 2016
42      A   2013-08-04        Yes Jan 2017
43      A   2013-08-04        Yes Feb 2017
44      A   2013-08-04        Yes Mar 2017
45      A   2013-08-04        Yes Apr 2017
46      B   2011-12-23         No Dec 2011
47      C   2014-09-03        Yes Sep 2014
48      C   2014-09-03        Yes Oct 2014
49      C   2014-09-03        Yes Nov 2014
50      C   2014-09-03        Yes Dec 2014
51      C   2014-09-03        Yes Jan 2015
52      C   2014-09-03        Yes Feb 2015
53      C   2014-09-03        Yes Mar 2015
54      C   2014-09-03        Yes Apr 2015
55      C   2014-09-03        Yes May 2015
56      C   2014-09-03        Yes Jun 2015
57      C   2014-09-03        Yes Jul 2015
58      C   2014-09-03        Yes Aug 2015
59      C   2014-09-03        Yes Sep 2015
60      C   2014-09-03        Yes Oct 2015
61      C   2014-09-03        Yes Nov 2015
62      C   2014-09-03        Yes Dec 2015
63      C   2014-09-03        Yes Jan 2016
64      C   2014-09-03        Yes Feb 2016
65      C   2014-09-03        Yes Mar 2016
66      C   2014-09-03        Yes Apr 2016
67      C   2014-09-03        Yes May 2016
68      C   2014-09-03        Yes Jun 2016
69      C   2014-09-03        Yes Jul 2016
70      C   2014-09-03        Yes Aug 2016
71      C   2014-09-03        Yes Sep 2016
72      C   2014-09-03        Yes Oct 2016
73      C   2014-09-03        Yes Nov 2016
74      C   2014-09-03        Yes Dec 2016
75      C   2014-09-03        Yes Jan 2017
76      C   2014-09-03        Yes Feb 2017
77      C   2014-09-03        Yes Mar 2017
78      C   2014-09-03        Yes Apr 2017
```

Comment: Seems like the best option to me

Comment: looks good, I just get the following error when creating the "monthly_series": 

Error in seq.int(r1$mon, 12 * (to0$year - r1$year) + to0$mon, by) : 
  'from' must be a finite number.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This error means that the `from` part of `seq.Date` is not recognised as a date. In my example, I'm using `min(as.Date(df$Member_since))`. Check the equivalent of `str(df$Member_since)`. In my example, this is: `chr [1:3] "2013-08-04..."` You could also type in the minimum dat directly like so: `from=as.Date("2011-12-23")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that I have an issue that R does not recognize the variable "member_since" as dates. I just don't understand how I can convert this? Sorry I tried to interpret your comment for quiet some time and just don't get anywhere further ...

Comment: What do you get when you do this `str(df$Member_since)` (with your real data)

Comment: I entered: monthly_series <- (seq.Date(str(df$Member_since),
                            as.Date("2017-05-01"),by="months"))

Comment: Error in seq.Date(str(df$member_since), as.Date("2017-05-01"),  : 
  'from' muss "Date" Objekt sein

Comment: No just put this in the console: `str(df$Member_since)` This is just to know what is the structure. Based on what you get, we'll know how to transform to a data object

Comment: Date[1:244102], format: "2015-05-07" "2013-04-04" "2015-05-01" "2016-02-18" "2013-12-07" "2014-05-21" "2013-01-29" ...

Comment: It's already a date. You only need `seq.Date(min(df$member_since), as.Date("2017-05-01"), by="months") `

Comment: really sorry but now it says: 'from' needs to have length 1

Comment: forgot the `min`: ``seq.Date(min(df$member_since), as.Date("2017-05-01"), by="months") ``

Comment: it seems to be cursed. The error is now: 'from' must be a finite number

Comment: try this: `my_min <- min(df$member_since);monthly_series <- (seq.Date(my_min,as.Date("2017-05-01"),by="months"))
`

Comment: unfortunately, it did not change it

Comment: Just out of curiosity (and without reading all previous comments) does my answer work?

Comment: @Neicooo What if you tried to wirte the from directly like so: `monthly_series <- seq.Date(as.Date("2011-01-11"),as.Date("2017-05-01"),by="months")`

Comment: @P Lapointe Thanks for all the help so far. It is running now. Unfortunately, the output is not as desired: the function creates a column called "month" and adds the "member_since" information in it and multiplies the existing entries (I'm not sure by what number) creating complete duplicates, thus not filling up the 'gaps' entries between "member_since" and "May 2017" ...

Comment: @Neicooo Not sure what to tell you. It's working with your example. I would look at the differences between your question example and your real life data.

Comment: @P Lapointe: Thank the code is working now. unfortunately, not exactly as I wanted. I edited the example above. Would it be possible to adapt your code somehow? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea via Base R,

```
#convert variables to dates and characters,
df$Member_since <- as.Date(df$Member_since, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
df[c(1, 3)] <- lapply(df[c(1,3)], as.character)
```

> ```
> str(df)
> 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
> $ Person      : chr  "A" "B" "C"
> $ Member_since: Date, format: "2013-08-04" "2011-12-23" "2014-09-03"
> $ Applicable  : chr  "Yes" "No" "Yes"
> ```

---

```
#create a list with monthly sequence of dates
l1 <- sapply(df$Member_since[df$Applicable == 'Yes'], function(i) 
                                        seq.Date(i, as.Date('2017-05-01'), by = 'month'))
#Create an extra variable based on the lengths of l1 to act as counter for expanding the data frame
df$cnt[df$Applicable == 'Yes'] <- lengths(l1)
#Change NA to 1 so it does not expand
df[is.na(df)] <- 1
#expand data frame
df1 <- df[rep(rownames(df), df$cnt),]
#create your Month variable by substituting the dates from l1
df1$Month[df1$Applicable == 'Yes'] <- format(do.call(c, l1), format = '%b %Y')
#take care of the NAs emerged from applicable being NO
df1$Month <- mapply(function(x, y) 
                replace(x, is.na(x), format(y, '%b %Y')), df1$Month, df1$Member_since)
#drop unwanted columns
df1$cnt <- NULL

head(df1)
#    Person Member_since Applicable    Month
#1        A   2013-08-04        Yes Aug 2013
#1.1      A   2013-08-04        Yes Sep 2013
#1.2      A   2013-08-04        Yes Oct 2013
#1.3      A   2013-08-04        Yes Nov 2013
#1.4      A   2013-08-04        Yes Dec 2013
#1.5      A   2013-08-04        Yes Jan 2014

tail(df1)
#     Person Member_since Applicable    Month
#3.26      C   2014-09-03        Yes Nov 2016
#3.27      C   2014-09-03        Yes Dec 2016
#3.28      C   2014-09-03        Yes Jan 2017
#3.29      C   2014-09-03        Yes Feb 2017
#3.30      C   2014-09-03        Yes Mar 2017
#3.31      C   2014-09-03        Yes Apr 2017
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Person = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"
), class = "factor"), Member_since = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("2011-12-23", 
"2013-08-04", "2014-09-03"), class = "factor"), Applicable = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Person", 
"Member_since", "Applicable"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I get the following error when creating l1: Error in seq.int(r1$mon, 12 * (to0$year - r1$year) + to0$mon, by) :   'from' must be a finite number 
I'm pretty sure that my variable member_since is in the correct format as it has the following format: Date[1:244102], format: "2015-05-07" "2013-04-04" ...

Answer (score 1):

You should check this package out: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/padr/vignettes/padr.html

Your answer will look something like this: `df2 <- df %>% filter(Applicable == "Yes") %>% pad(group = "Person", start_val = Member_since, end_val = "2017-05-04", interval = "month")`. 
I would then do `append_df <- df %>% filter(Applicable == "No")` so you have all the "No" answers in a separated dataset. 
Finally, you can add back in with `final_df <- bind_rows(df2, append_df`. This should get you on the right path.

Comment: Where did you get `pad` from? Also did you check that it works? The `no` applicables also need work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `plyr` alternative to the many options you have. Your example data:

```
library(plyr)

df <- read.table( text = "Person Member_since  Applicable
A      2013-08-04    Yes
B      2011-12-23    No
C      2014-09-03    Yes", header = TRUE)
```

Make sure `Member_since` is in date format:

```
df$Member_since <- as.Date(df$Member_since)
```

Use `adply` to iterate over the rows and build new rows with sequential months if `Applicable` is "Yes", and just the original row if `Applicable` is "No".

```
df2<-adply(df, 1, function(x) {
  if(x$Applicable == "Yes"){
    data.frame(x, month = format(
      seq.Date(as.Date(x$Member_since), as.Date("2017-06-01"), by = "month"),  
      "%b %Y"))
  }
  else{
    data.frame(x, month = format(x$Member_since, "%b %Y"))
  }
}
)

> head(df2);tail(df2)
  Person Member_since Applicable    month
1      A   2013-08-04        Yes Aug 2013
2      A   2013-08-04        Yes Sep 2013
3      A   2013-08-04        Yes Oct 2013
4      A   2013-08-04        Yes Nov 2013
5      A   2013-08-04        Yes Dec 2013
6      A   2013-08-04        Yes Jan 2014
   Person Member_since Applicable    month
75      C   2014-09-03        Yes Dec 2016
76      C   2014-09-03        Yes Jan 2017
77      C   2014-09-03        Yes Feb 2017
78      C   2014-09-03        Yes Mar 2017
79      C   2014-09-03        Yes Apr 2017
80      C   2014-09-03        Yes May 2017
```